# Update webpart sharepoint 2013 with jquery

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, jquery, updatepanel

I want to update my custom webpart, I tried the UpdatePanel but it updated all the Webparts in my page, so I looked for the Webpart Id then I wrote a script :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        SetTimeout(ab, 5000);}
    );
    Function ab(){
       var a = documents.getelementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartctl00_ctl47_g_fb819f8a_159d_45c7_b76b_8c696aab54ad');
    }
</script>
```

Am I missing soemthing?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I formatted the script for you, but I do not understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to refresh my custom webpart

Comment: check this one http://almondlabs.com/blog/update-web-part-properties-csom/

Comment: All your script does is fetching a DOM element. What does refresh mean in your scenario?